# getting video duration 0 after video src loaded dynamically, tried loadedmetadata but its not working in html5/phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, video, html5-video

I have a video file which iam fetching from the gallery of my android phone through the phonegap's **navigator.camera.getPicture** api, its giving me the path of the video chosen by me, then i am passing the video path to the **src** attribute of the video, so here the path of the video is dynamic, now my problem is, i need the duration of the video which i have chosen, i have tried in few expected ways as shown below, but it didn't work for me.

```
 <script>
 video=document.getElementById('videoAction');
 console.log(video.duration);            // Didn't work for me.
 </script>
```

Also tried using loadededmetadata eventlistener.

```
  <script>
  video=document.getElementById('videoAction');
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  console.log(video.duration);               //Didn't work for me.
  });
  </script>
```

Also tried using buffered output methods

```
   <script>
   video=document.getElementById('videoAction');
   console.log(video.buffered.end(0));            // Didn't work for me.
   </script>
```

the src for the video is dynamic and its playing the video nicely, but i need the video duration in seconds, none of the technique have worked for me till now.
Does any one have a nice answer for this, any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)